# Dialogflow multiple instances of bot

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a dialogflow bot that helps a user order an item from a menu. I would like to spawn multiple instances of the bot, because when two people talk to the bot they are talking to the same instance, and the bot takes both of their inputs into account. What is the correct way of making separate instances for each user?

Comment: Your question is very vague. We don't know how you have things setup currently, so it is difficult to answer you. Showing your code, and as much configuration as you can, would go a long way to helping you actually solve your problem. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different session Ids for different users.
[Detect Intent Request with the session Id](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.environments.users.sessions/detectIntent)

Comment: Yup, this was the right answer. I generate a new sessionId for each user and the bot treats them separately

Answer (score 0):

This is generally a coding problem on your side - usually meaning you're using global variables instead of storing information that needs to be maintained over the session in Context parameters.